# Submitting tasks that depend on other tasks risks deadlock unless the pool is unbounded

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

Quote from Chapter 8 of "Java Concurrency in Practice":

> Mixing long-running and short-running tasks risks “clogging” the pool unless it is
> very large; submitting tasks that depend on other tasks risks deadlock unless
> the pool is unbounded.

Why thread pool very large, mixing long-running and short-running tasks avoid “clogging” the pool;
Pool is unbounded means task queue is unbounded?
Why thread pool unbounded, submitting tasks that depend on other tasks avoid  deadlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pool is unbounded" means there is no limit to the number of threads in the pool.

Therefore, an unlimited number of tasks can execute concurrently.

Therefore, you cannot get into a deadlock where executing task T1 depends on task T2 which is unable to execute because there are no available threads.

---

With long-running tasks, the smaller the number of available threads, the greater the risk of all threads being occupied by long-running tasks, thus there is no thread left to run short tasks.

The pool needs to be large enough to accommodate the peak number of long tasks plus however many short tasks might be needed to satisfy dependencies.  It seems better to have separate pools; it is easier to reason about.

Comment: "Pool is very large" and "Pool is unbounded" in quote both refer to the number of threads in the thread pool?

Comment: Yes.  Though to be specific, it refers to the limit on the number of threads that can exist, not the number that do exist right now.  Some pools dynamically create and destroy threads according to need.